# Linq LeftJoin Nullable object must have a value Error

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

> When i use y in my select it has "Nullable object must have a value" error

```
 var products = productQuery.
        .GroupJoin(customerProductPrices,
        p => p.Id,
        pp => pp.ProductId,
                 (p, pp) => new { Product = p, CustomerProductPrice = pp })
                .SelectMany(
                   x => x.CustomerProductPrice.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                   (x, y) => new ProductFilterResultModel
                   {
                      Id = x.Product.Id,                           
                       Price = y != null  ? y.Price : 0
                   });
```

Comment: Can `y.Price` have null values? Is it nullable field? If so, you need to make `ProductFilterResultModel.Price` also nullable.

Comment: What is `productQuery` (type) and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your GroupJoin purpose? I don't have entities, from the example I can rewrite:

```cs
var products = customerProductPrices.Select(pp => new ProductFilterResultModel
{
    Id = pp.Product.Id,
    Price = pp != null ? pp.Price : 0
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error,
Thats because of my ProductFilterResultModel model, some properties in this model was not nullable but the datas which fetch from database and related to these properties was null. I change my nullable properties required type to the nullable type.